# How can I map a docker volume to a google compute engine persistent disk

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, kubernetes

I've gone through the steps to create a persistent disk in google compute engine and attach it to a running VM instance. I've also created a docker image with a VOLUME directive. It runs fine locally, in the docker run command, i can pass a -v option to mount a host directory as the volume. I thought there would be a similar command in kubectl, but I don't see one. How can I mount my persistent disk as the docker volume?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your pod spec, you may specify a Kubernetes [`gcePersistentDisk`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/volumes/#gcepersistentdisk) volume (the `spec.volumes` field) and where to mount that volume into containers (the `spec.containers.volumeMounts` field). Here's an example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: gcr.io/google_containers/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-pd
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    # This GCE PD must already exist.
    gcePersistentDisk:
      pdName: my-data-disk
      fsType: ext4
```

Read more about Kubernetes volumes: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/volumes

Comment: thanks! it was a little confusing to understand how docker/kubernetes/google cloud all worked together to do this.